# Django ValueError Cannot assign "'testing'": "Profile.artist" must be a "Artist" instance

Tags: python, django

I have created a form and have set the foreign key 'artist' as a CharField so users can freely input the artist's name and it would be created if it doens't exist.  I am getting the following error when inputting data in the artist field:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'testing'": "Profile.artist" must be a "Artist" instance

Here is my models.py:

```
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mix = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def profile_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()         
            form = ProfileForm(None) #clears the form for new submission
            context = {
                "form": form,
                "instance": instance,
            }
            return render(request, "profile_form.html", context)
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(None)
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "profile_form.html", context)
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile, Artist

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "artist",
            "title",
            "mix",
            "genre",
            ]

    artist = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)

    def clean_artist(self, commit=True):
        artist = self.cleaned_data.get("artist")
        if not artist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Artist is a required field.")
        else:
            artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)
            self.cleaned_data['artist'] = artist
            return super(ProfileForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be calling super `clean()` inside your `clean_artist` method. Nor does that method take a `commit` parameter.

Comment: the `commit=True` parameter isn't needed either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clean_artist` method should return the cleaned value of the artist field. so instead of

```
artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)
self.cleaned_data['artist'] = artist
return super(ProfileForm, self).clean()
```

do

```
artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)
return artist
```

I am not sure though if it is best practice to rewrite the type of a field in the clean method, as it could pose problems if there are errors in the form and it needs to be rendered again with a artist instance as value.

I would probably remove the `artist` field from `Meta.fields` and do the `Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)` and set the artist field of the instance in the `save` method of the form.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but when I remove the `artist` field from `Meta.fields`, the form renders Artist field on the bottom instead of the top of the form.  Submitting the form w/ data, I get **profiles_profile.artist_id may not be NULL**

Comment: You can define the field order by using Form.field_order (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order) from django 1.9 on.

Comment: You need to add a `save()` method to your form that sets the artist manually on the profile.